# Extracting fields in word files and export it to database

Tags: aspose, aspose.words

I would need some advice for using Aspose word for .net. For one of my projects, I had a requirement where the data "fields" from word documents had to be extracted and exported to a database. May I know how should i start? I have tried the demo. However, I still have doubts with the implementation. All the fields is in a table of different columns and rows.

- The demo seems to be able to extract data from one word file only. Is
  it possible to extract data from multiple word file with different
  filename? For example, Test1.doc and Test2.doc.
- The demo doesn't seems to find my word file with "fields" it shows
  the error "file not found".
- I'm thinking of using Aspose word to "literate" the word files, read
  the "field" contents and save it to the respective columns in
  "database". Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use following code example to get the values of FormFields.

```
Document doc = new Document(MyDir + "in.docx");

foreach (FormField formField in doc.Range.FormFields)
{
    if (formField.Type == FieldType.FieldFormDropDown)
        Console.WriteLine(formField.DropDownItems[formField.DropDownSelectedIndex]);
    else if (formField.Type == FieldType.FieldFormTextInput)
        Console.WriteLine(formField.Result);
}
```

I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.